# The "First Questions" tab should be the default for the Review page

Tags: discussion, questions, review

If we want to encourage users to vote on questions, maybe the default tab on the review page should be the "First Questions" tab, instead of the "First Answers" tab?

Comment: And by the way, welcome to the Meta site! Please note that downvotes here mean something different than they do on the main Stack Overflow site. Specifically, they indicate that other users *disagree* with what you've proposed. They don't mean that you've asked a bad question.

Comment: Thank you @Cody. None taken :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [/review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) is not designed for the regular browsing of questions. It's not really where we want to encourage people to vote on questions. You should keep doing that from the [main page](https://stackoverflow.com/), as usual.

Instead, it is intended *solely* to allow those users who care about improving the overall quality of the site to invest time in screening various categories of "high-risk" posts, and if a problem is found, flagging them for moderator attention.

Of course, if you happen to find a post in the /review tab that is worth voting up, you should certainly feel free to do so! But this is not the primary or intended purpose of that page.

I assume the reason that the "First Answers" tab is displayed first is because it's extremely common that a new user posts something that is not an answer. Lots of users are apparently accustomed to other "forum"-style sites, where I understand it's accepted practice to post "noise" or "discussion" answers. These are not the types of "answers" that we want to appear on Stack Overflow, so finding and flagging them is very helpful in preventing the noise from drowning out the useful content.

Comment: People that are posting their first question are usually newer to the site than people posting their first answer, I would think.  Therefore, they probably need at least an equal amount of guidance and edits to those people submitting the answers.  I don't think the OP is asking to view the questions that way, but trying to adjust what is presented first.

Comment: @jonsca: I disagree that questions are the priority in the /review tab. If you want to clean up newly-posted questions, the easiest way is to click on the "Questions" button in the top navigation bar. They're sorted in most-recent-first order by default. New answers are harder to find this way.

Comment: I'll certainly give you that new answers are harder to find.  The review attraction is that you can isolate the first questions from a given poster.  I personally don't use the review as much as I just view the new questions via the Questions button on the main page like you said, but I believed the OP's intentions were getting dismissed as totally unfounded.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the pages under /review is to review questions and answers that could be problematic, or answers that are not really answers. Its purpose is not to let users vote for questions, for which there are already pages showing the recent questions.